# How can i add and remove a class from an specific element?

Tags: javascript

i'm making a to do list with only javascript and css. When i add the task, it creates an article with a h1 and 2 icons. The check icon and delete icon. When i click the check icon, it add the class that changes the text style to line-through. The problem is that it's applying to all h1, and i want it to apply only to one specific h1.

```
function TaskName() {
      window.taskName = {};
      window.taskName.handdleClick = () => {
    
        const $Task = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
      $Task.forEach((e) => {
        e.classList.toggle("task-check");
      };
    
      window.taskName.delete = () => {
        ItemRemoval();
      };
      let $Input = document.getElementById("input-item");
      let $task = $Input.value;
      return /*html*/ `
          <article id='task-article'>
            <h1 id='task-name'>${$task}</h1>
            <img src='images/check 1.png' alt='Completar tarefa' onclick='taskName.handdleClick()' id='check-icon'>
            <img src='images/delete.svg' alt='Deletar tarefa' onclick='taskName.delete()' id='delete-icon'>
          </article>
        `;
    }
```

Comment: Well you get all `h1` elements (`document.querySelectorAll("h1");`) and then toggle the class `"task-check"` on all of them. Just call `classList.toggle` on a specific `h1` element if you want to just affect one

Comment: Yes, but that's the thing, how can i add the class to that specific h1? Because when i click the add button, it create a article with all those 3 things. So if i keep clicking the add button, i'll have many articles with many h1.

Comment: Could you share the working code like jsfiddle or codepen link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem starts at the structure of your code:

- there's a function called `TaskName` that does a lot of things: creating HTML, `deleting` something from somewhere, handling a click event
- you use the global namespace (`window`) to handle things

What do you need, if you want a `Todo` app?

- a list of todos (probably an array)
- a function to add a new `Todo` to the list of todos
- a function to remove a `Todo` item from the list of todos
- a function that sets 1 `Todo` item to `done` (OK, usually toggle between `done` and `not done`)

Here's a snippet that does this:

```js
// list of todos & list manipulation functions
let todos = []

const addTodo = (newTodo, todos) => [...todos, newTodo]
const removeTodo = (idToRemove, todos) => todos.filter(({ id }) => idToRemove != id)
const toggleTodoDone = (idToToggle, todos) => todos.map(({ id, done, ...rest }) => id == idToToggle ? { id, done: !done, ...rest } : { id, done, ...rest })

const getTodoItem = (label) => ({
  id: Date.now(),
  done: false,
  label,
})

// DOM manipulation & event handling
const input = document.getElementById("input-add-todo")
const btnAdd = document.getElementById("btn-add-todo")
const container = document.getElementById("container")

const resetInput = () => input.value = ''

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const label = input.value
  if (label) {
    const newTodo = getTodoItem(label)
    todos = addTodo(newTodo, todos)
    updateContainer(container, todos)
    resetInput()
  }
})

const getTodoHtml = (todo) => {
  const doneClass = todo.done ? ' done' : ''
  return `
    <div
      class="todo-item${doneClass}"
      data-id="${todo.id}"
    >
      ${todo.label} - ${todo.done}
      <button class="remove-todo" data-id="${todo.id}">X</button>
    </div>
  `
}

const getTodoListHtml = (todos) => todos.map(getTodoHtml).join('')

const registerEventHandlers = (container) => {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-item')
  els.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const id = el.dataset.id
    todos = toggleTodoDone(id, todos)
    updateContainer(container, todos)
  }))
  
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-todo')
  btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    const id = btn.dataset.id
    todos = removeTodo(id, todos)
    updateContainer(container, todos)
  }))
  
}

const updateContainer = (container, todos) => {
  container.innerHTML = getTodoListHtml(todos)
  registerEventHandlers(container)
}
```

```css
.todo-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.todo-item.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input-add-todo" />
  <button id="btn-add-todo">ADD TODO</button>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```